# Interface between ListAdapter and Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an interesting problem I'm trying to solve involving communication between a list view adapter and a fragment. I'm quite new to using Interfaces, so please bear with me.

In my list view adapter, I need to trigger a change in the parent fragment - specifically, the `int` member `mediaId`:

```
FragmentTitle extends Fragment implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener,
             MediaListView.OnMediaTitleSelectedListener {

    private int mediaId;
    // Other properties, methods, etc


    // Required interface method implementation
    @Override
    public void onMediaTitleSelected(int i) {
        mediaId = i;
    }

}
```

I've written an interface in the MediaListView adapter class as such:

```
public interface OnMediaTitleSelectedListener {
    void onMediaTitleSelected(int i);
}
```

Within the `getView()` method of the adapter (`MediaListView`), there's an onClick method invoked:

```
...
// mediaId instantiated here
final int itemMediaId = foo.getMediaId();

OnMediaTitleSelectedListener callback;

item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // I need to "trigger" the event here
        callback.onMediaTitleSelected(itemMediaId);

       // Other stuff done here... yadda yadda
    }
}
```

Now, I know I need to instantiate this interface, lest trigger a NullPointerException, and I tried to do so within the `MediaListView` class:

```
OnMediaTitleSelectedListener callback = new OnMediaTitleSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMediaTitleSelected(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMediaTitleSelected: "+ i);
    }
};
```

The above indeed logs the clicked result, but since this is in the `MediaListView` class, it doesn't fire the event to `FragmentTitle`, even though both these are side-by-side in the same layout. I also don't understand why the above is necessary, as I have no use for this interface implementation in `MediaListView`, only in `FragmentTitle`.

The reason for all this is to update the Bundle `outState` for configuration changes - `FragmentTitle`, of which `MeidaListView` is a child needs to be updated of the last clicked `mediaId` so that the same thing shows up after screen rotation.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Right now, I'm adding the value to static member in another class to "hold" the value of `mediaId`, but something tells me this isn't the "correct" way to go about this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're instatiating the callback object (`OnMediaTitleSelectedListener`) locally, even though that object must be the `FragmentTitle`. Because `FragmentTitle` implements the OnMediaTitleSelectedListener interface, it can be passed as a `OnMediaTitleSelectedListener` object in the constructor of your Adapter. Somehow like this:

```
public MediaListView(OnMediaTitleSelectedListener omtsl, ...){
   callback = omtsl;
}
```

And when you instantiate the `MediaListView` adapter, you should pass the `FragmentTitle` object as `OnMediaTitleSelectedListener`:

```
FragmentTitle fragmentTitle = new FragmentTitle(...);
MediaListView mediaListView = new MediaListView(fragmentTitle, ...);
```

This way your callback object will refer to the `FragmentTitle`, and will call **its** `onMediaTitleSelected()` method, rather than the local logging method, like you implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
OnMediaTitleSelectedListener callback = new OnMediaTitleSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onMediaTitleSelected(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onMediaTitleSelected: "+ i);
}
};
```

You should give your FragmentTitle as the Interface when creating the MediaListView, like

```
MediaListView mListView = new MediaListView(this,....)
```

where constructor of MediaListView would be like

```
public MediaListView(OnMediaSelectedListener mListener,....){
    this.mListener = mListener
    ...
```